# Is it possible to make an image transparent in a gradient?

Tags: css, transparency

I want to do it using CSS. I don't want to the whole image to have equal transparency on every pixel.

Comment: Via what methods? The simplest answer is for you to just create a 24bit PNG with whatever transparency you want built into it. If you're asking about doing this *via CSS* that's an entirely different question.

Comment: I mean CSS, I got answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use CSS3 Mask property. A nice article about that: http://css-tricks.com/webkit-image-wipes/

Comment: you are rigth, here it is: `<img src="kate.png" style="-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)))">`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done!

```
/* using the mozilla kit */
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 95%
);

/* using webkit */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(50,50,50,0.8)),
  to(rgba(80,80,80,0.2)), color-stop(.5,#333333)
);
```

These should work in all browsers: http://www.leon-zinger.com/css-tricks/css3-gradients-with-opacity-works-with-ie and http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/bulletproof-cross-browser-rgba-backgrounds/

Comment: dude, you dont get the question:)

Comment: @scythargon - As I understand, you want to have full opacity on one side of the image, and then have it "gradient" to transparency.